# Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi & custom styles

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles, windows-ribbon-framework

I just started playing around with the [Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi](https://github.com/TurboPack/RibbonFramework), which is great by the way, but I noticed a white band at the top of my form's client area if I activate a custom style supplied by Delphi (Project Options > Application > Appearance), Cyan Dusk for example:
[Ribbon & Custom Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiQYO.png)

The white band doesn't appear when no custom style is applied. I noticed the same behavior when using DevExpress Skins.

Is this an issue with the framework? I'm using Delphi XE4.

Thanks.

Comment: Styles aren't very well implemented, worse in old versions.

Comment: @RRUZ is the styles guru. Some of his fixes and extensions could be found here: [vcl-styles-utils](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils).

Comment: The core of the problem is that VCL Styles only applies styles on controls which are explicitly designed to be styled. This is typically all the controls which come pre-packaged with Delphi. However, it does not necessarily apply to third-party controls. Some third-party libraries *might* utilize styles, but the Ribbons are not exclusively styled. As mentioned though, the `vcl-styles-utils` *might* have a fix for ribbons.

Comment: You also **must** be aware of this: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2016-may-ribbon-controls.html

Answer (score 2):

The VCL Styles doesn't supports the Windows Ribbon Framework or any Ribbon UI.  However is technically possible use the VCL Styles and the ribbon UI in the same App, but  that requires disable the styling in the form (and controls) where the Ribbon UI is used.

Comment: As of XE6 VCL Tribbon works pretty well with VCL Styles, i use those together for quite a few years allready.

Comment: In XE6 the TRibbon compatibility with the VCL Styles was improved, but also require which you play with the `StyleElements` property for disable the styling in some controls.

Comment: I just played around with the StyleElements property of the form containing the ribbon, and it seems it is specifically the seBorder value that comes into conflit. This could be a good workaround for me as I would be able to disable it for the main form which would contain the ribbon menu and have the style enabled for all other forms of my application. Thanks!